# WordPress Title Tag Not Changing

Tags: tags, title

I'm working on my WordPress testing website and I'm trying to change the title tag to the very short hyphen. (-) I've added a code into the functions.php file that allows me to change the title tag.

```
add_filter ('document_title_separator', 'wpse_set_document_title_separator') ;

function
wpse_set_document_title_separator ($sep)
{
    return ('-') ;
}
```

So at the part in the code, ('-') is where I've placed my desired title tag the SHORT hyphen but instead it remains as the default (—) LONG hyphen... Help me pls.

Comment: Did you try setting up a higher priority for your add_filter? Something like: 
`add_filter ('document_title_separator', 'wpse_set_document_title_separator', 999) ;`

Comment: Didn't work... :(

Comment: If you [look at the filter in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1048), you can see why this happens. After the filter is applied, the [`wptexturize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) function on line 1067 converts short hyphens to long hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` function doesn't require `()`. So you'd want your function to look like this:

```
function wpse_set_document_title_separator ( $sep) {
    return '-';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'wpse_set_document_title_separator' );
```

Comment: I mean I can change the title separator to anything else like | for example and it works. I just cannot get the short hyphen.

Comment: Try `return '&dash;';`

Comment: Alright, that literally just made the title tag &dash;.

Comment: I forgot to ask, are you running an plugin like Yoast SEO? I just tried the above code and it was working fine as I originally typed it. Also, it appears that WordPress defaults to `-` as the separator so something else like a plugin might be overriding.

Comment: Hey there I solved it, I just went through a list of hyphen symbols until I found the right one. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: You're welcome. Out of curiosity, how did the return end up looking?